# How to determine which allele GRCh37 has?

Tags: dna-sequencing, human-genome

is there a website where I can search GRCh37 by location or rs IDs, to determine which allele it has at a specific location?

I think http://grch37.ensembl.org/ might be the answer to my question, but I'm not sure if when it says the "ancestral" allele on the results page, if that allele is the one in GRCh37. Or if it'll tell me which one GRCh37 has somewhere else on the page.

Also as a side note: I assume GRCh37 only has one copy of each chromosome (i.e. it can't be heterozygous for something?).

Comment: Why are you using GRCh37/hg19? It's pretty out of date. If GRCh38 is ok, you might consider poking around the UCSC browser with the SNP track turned on: https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg38&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chrX%3A15560138%2D15602945&hgsid=850023477_A5lwHGMEgIZ6APPQrAAOmPBJcTzT

Comment: (it does have GRCh37 data but it may not be convenient to access what you need)

Comment: I have data in terms of GRCh37, and haven't looked into translating it, but maybe I should. And thank you for the link! I will take a look.

Comment: Ok- UCSC browser has a tool to do the liftover from hg19 to hg38 if that is helpful: https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgLiftOver

Comment: Oh that's great, thank you!